# How to create table from Hibernate POJO class ? How to implement reverse enginnering strategies in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, reverse-engineering

I have witten the POJO class, *.cfg.xml file, *.hbm.xml file and hibernate code to retrieve data.

But I didn't created any table. Is there any tag available in hibernate which will create table by using configuration files.

How to implement reverse engineering in hibernate ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

You can actually set a configuration property and instruct hibernate to create the database schema for you.

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = create-drop | update
```

See this link [Asking hibernate to generate schema for you](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-2008/jw-08-hibernate-annotations.html)